# Win 7 not reconnecting to domain Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-domain

Just updated my drivers on my computer. It disconnected from a domain network and now it will not reconnect. All settings ate correct under computer name and I can see other computers on the network under start -> network. It now shows "Network 4" where the domain name was before. What settings(s) could have changed?

Comment: It's probably your network settings that are wrong. We need more information, like whether you have DHCP on the network. You may need a static entry for DNS just to get around the problem temporarily.

Comment: It looks lite it's on DHCP. I'm in the process of copying the config of another computer, so if you have any suggestions of what to look for it would be appreciated.

Comment: A static entry for DNS would be my first aim. Deleting all the old settings would be number two.

Comment: Ok, I have copied all of settings that I could find from the other computer and it still does not work. I have even assigned myself a static ip (I pinged to see if it was empty) wins server, dns... The whole shabang but I still can't connect. Could this be a server side thing? I did notice that I was not being assigned a DNS server, or other things that I would expect to be assigned.

Comment: If you assigned a static address, you also have to assign a static DNS entry. Did you do this? I'm afraid it's not very clear from your description what you've been trying. You simply have to be sure your network settings are correct before you can further troubleshoot. Perhaps you should roll back your network card drivers to the previous version and leave that alone.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a sys admin. and I am new to domain networking. I have assigned a static ip, DNS, servers, wins server and subnet mask. All (except the ip) coppied from a computer that is currently on the network. Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: Please put your resolution into an answer so that we can mark this as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems that It was connectify that installed an addon to the Ethernet adapter. So I disabled The addon (right click -> properties) by unchecking the connectify box. I also diabled VM network services and IPv6 because out domain does not use it.